# Is it possible to restore data from a non-persistent DM snapshot after crash?

Tags: crash, snapshot, device-mapper

I often use non-persistent device mapper snapshots, an example table looks like this:

```
0 10485760 snapshot /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdc6 N 16
```

In case of a crash, I still have both `/dev/sdc3` and `/dev/sdc6` because disks are non-volatile. But is it possible to get that `snapshot` device back, or at least recover the changes from `/dev/sdc6` somehow?
I know that persistent snapshots exist for my purpose but I'm still curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible. Some data may still be there, just not in a way that makes sense to a filesystem...

---

A snapshot considers your block device as chunks of data, with a certain chunk size. As writes come in, each affected chunk is preserved by copying it over to the snapshot device.

Filesystem writes are usually quite random, so this can happen in any order. The copied chunk ends up being at a different offset.

So the snapshot stores metadata, which is the relation between (old offset <-> new offset).

With a transient snapshot, this store only exists in memory. It is lost when you reboot or otherwise deactivate the snapshot.

---

Without this metadata, what do you have?

Essentially you are looking at "random chunks of data".

In order to get that snapshot device back, you would have to be able to somehow determine the original offset of each and every chunk that was copied over.

But this can usually not be done. You don't know where these chunks originally came from. You don't even know if those are chunks at all, or just old data that was there before the snapshot was created.

And even if you could solve this puzzle, it would only work if no more writes happened to the origin device while the snapshot wasn't active. If the device was mounted read-write, and chunks of data that aren't in the snapshot got overwritten, you're not just missing metadata anymore. You're missing data.

So all in all, it's considered irrecoverable.

---

Exceptions are possible.

If a number of chunks were copied in order, or if whatever data you're looking for was small enough to fit in a single chunk, you might still get lucky and find it. Same way you can get lucky and recover something from a single disk out of a failed raid5 set, if it happened to be small enough to fit in a single chunk of data. If you're happy with recovering bits of data without the help of a filesystem.

You could have data that somehow knows its own offset. For example if you write the output of `hexdump -C` to a block device, and then snapshot that. hexdump prints offsets in every line so you can derive offsets from data. That's assuming hexdump didn't skip any lines...

If you're using full disk encryption (LUKS) and you snapshot the entire LUKS device. Your snapshot will have chunks of completely random (encrypted) data. LUKS doesn't know the offset of that data either, but as long as you still have the LUKS header and know the key, you could attempt to decrypt each chunk for each offset; and if you find an offset where it decrypts to non-random data, that should be the correct one. But that's assuming all encrypted data was plain-text. Once you encrypt random data, you don't know either way.

If you have a use-case where writes are not random but completely deterministic, you could be able to reproduce metadata by repeating the same actions on a new snapshot. If you know you only used dd to write data with seek and count, and in which order, perhaps it could be done.

But these are cases you don't usually encounter in practice. It just doesn't work that well. There are no tools to help you in this endeavor.

Comment: Sorry, my description of snapshots is a bit wrong in this answer, if you're using snapshot target directly instead of the lvm way. The core issue remains the same though.